# grails define namespace for service

Tags: grails, service

Is there a way to define namespace for services, For example have 2 different services with the same name, and differentiated by the namespace (the namespace could be the version for example)

In Controller we can do

```
class ActionController {
    static namespace = 'v1'
}
```

Is there to do this in service, and how should we make the call in that case.

Thanks

Comment: No, not like the namespace for controllers. See if this helps: http://blog.jdriven.com/2015/01/grails-preventing-naming-collisions/

Comment: I have a service, that calls different services depending on the client connected. Right now i have to do an if condition on the client name and call the service accordingly